# Why can't I open the pdf file from a String?

Tags: flutter

What I want to succeed is simply to transform a raw String that is coming from an API endpoint to Uint8List, and with this operation, I just need to open the UintList like a pdf file with the help pdfx package.

For this purpose, I am using pdfx package.

with this package I can use this code;

```
String _raw = "SlZCRVJpMHhMallLSmNPa3c3ekR0c09mQ2pJZ01DQnZZbW9LUER3dlRHV bla bla bla" (coming from API)
```

and I am transforming the raw string to Uint8List with base64Decode(_raw) function help.

and my code is below;

```
_pdfController = PdfControllerPinch(document: PdfDocument.openData(base64Decode(_raw)), initialPage: 0);
```

but...

I am getting error; `PdfRendererException`, Can't open the file.

What I tried;

1. I copy that string and using these websites, confirm the coming String is correct and working. (I decode it with the second link and I copied decoded String to the first website and the pdf file shows up! so string must be correct.)

https://www.ipvoid.com/base64-to-pdf/
https://www.base64decode.org/

and, I tested the package with the asset file and it is working with asset files correctly.

So guys, what I am doing missing? Am I need to some convert process for utf8 or maybe something different?

any idea?

Comment: @KJ sorry for my poor english, but can you give me some code because ı couldn't understand the your meaning. "so the string is a string of a string thats odd you should only need to decode an incoming once if at all the pdf should be" what is mean ? And again, I am really sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Okay it is wasteful but it is not the answer, That string working with online decoders like as I said on my question so any idea for my problem ?

Comment: @KJ you are right, I will ask that but can you help me once again, I decode my raw string with online decoder and  I changed my raw data with like "JVBER bla bla" (coming from online decoder) and file shown up. So my question how can I change my current _raw data to JVBER version using with dart ?

Answer (score 0):

U can try to put it in a File(from flutter IO) after decoder it ...store it in the local storage by using path_provider .. and then open it by the pdf controller  as a file